erro "Variavel indefinido" não consigo resolver esso erro ajuda
<?PHP
$espaco = "<br>";
$strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_nestab') or die ('Erro ao cadastra');
$result_sql = "INSERT INTO tb_actividades(nome,data_atuacao,data_actual,cobranca) VALUES ('$Nome','$ultpagamento','$data_cads','$Porra')";
$resultado_sql = mysqli_query($strcon,$result_sql)or die ('Erro');
mysqli_close($strcon);


 $data1 = $dataPC;
 $data2 = $ultpagamento;
 $dia1=strtotime(  $dataPC );
 $dia2=strtotime( $ultpagamento );
 $dia = ( $dia2 - $dia1 ) / 86400 ." Dias";
echo " " .$dia .$espaco;
 if ($dia == "0 Dias") :
    $Porra = "0 dias vencid";
    
 else:
   
    $Porra = "ACTIV";

    endif
?>


Pergunta duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/597773/erro-variavel-indefinido  não adicione a mesma pergunta, pode clicar em "Editar" e alterar a primeira

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
